# Android Studio: 'name' attribute should be defined

Tags: android, android-resources

Today I have opened Android Studio and this is what I find:
[image]

and the same is happening for my resources files (strings, styles, dimensions, colors):
[image]

Comment: Have you defined `name` attribute? because it is a required field. Same goes in second image also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`<string>` and `<activity>` elements don't have the attribute called `'eventName'`. They have the required element `'name'` which in your case is missing.
Looks like you've made the search-and-replace operation and replaced `'name'` attributes with `'eventName'` by mistake. Revert this replacement and the issue will disappear.